# Card view scale animation

Tags: android, android-cardview

In my app i have a cardview which contains a text view and a button and the button is initially hidden and when the card view is clicked the button is shown. I don't know how to animate it into view when the button is shown. Can anyone suggest a good reference or tutorial to do this, either in code or in xml. Here is my code

This is my custom  row

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:cardCornerRadius="1dp"
android:elevation="5dp"
android:layout_margin="5dp">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="@dimen/customRowPadding">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtCustomRow"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:text="@string/sampleText"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnHidden"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hidden Button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

adapter onBindViewHolder

```
 public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.tv.setText(list.get(position));
    holder.Btn.setText("Hidden Button " + (position + 1));
    holder.Btn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

View Holder and clicklistener

```
static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView tv ;
    Button Btn;
    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        tv = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtCustomRow);
        Btn = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnHidden);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Btn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [**describe the problem**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For **API 11** or greater, the easiest way to do this is to use a [layout change animation](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/layout.html). So when you set visibility to `View.Visible` on a gone view, this will create space for your view in the layout and do a fade in animation from invisible to visible.

All you need to do is set this attribute on your parent layout:

```
android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
```

Comment: @sony: Make sure you add the `animateLayoutChanges` attribute on your `LinearLayout`, which is the direct parent of your button and text view.

Comment: It worked. I paced the "android:animateLayoutChanges="true"" in the root of the view not in the parent of the controls

Comment: is there any way to configure time (duration of this animation)?